# ASP.NET - Required Field Validator giving false negative errors on Listbox

Tags: asp.net, listbox, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Background: I have a bundles listbox that inherits values from the carriers listbox once a carrier is selected via a web service.

- I have a validationGroup on the button, I used Page.IsValid on the click handler and it says "Nothing".
- When i select different carriers in IE8 it resets the other form values but not in IE9.
- With Autopost=false on the lbCarriers, the Bundles listbox wont load any data.
- With CausesValidation="true" in "lbCarriers", Bundles listbox wont load any data either Do you know how to do that w Ajax?
- Do you know how I could do this w/ Ajax?

Problem: Using the required field validator on the bundles listbox is returning an a false erorr when I have bundles selected. When I click the Send Button, I get the "Select At Least 1 Bundle" Error Message but the invitation still sends out an i get an email.

Here's a screenshot of the application:

[image: Validation_Listbox_Error]

asp.net code on default.aspx page:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="style5">
            Carrier:<br />
            <font size="1">*Hold Ctrl Key Down to Select Multiple Carriers</font></td>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style7">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lbCarriers" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="true" 
                runat="server" Height="86px" Width="250px" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup">
            </asp:ListBox>
        </td>

        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style2">

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CarrierValidator" runat="server" Text="*"
                        ErrorMessage="Select At Least 1 Carrier"  ControlToValidate="lbCarriers"
                        ValidationGroup = "ValidationGroup" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td class="style1">
            Bundles:<br />
            <font size="1">*Hold Ctrl Key Down to Select Multiple Bundles</font></td>

   <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style6">
            <asp:ListBox ID="bundles" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server" Height="86px" 
                Width="250px" Enabled="True" 
                ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup" CausesValidation="True">
            </asp:ListBox>
   </td>

   <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="style2">
              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="BundleValidator" runat="server" Text="*"
                        ErrorMessage="Select At Least 1 Bundle" ControlToValidate="bundles"
                        ValidationGroup = "ValidationGroup" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    </td>
    </tr>

     <asp:Button ID="Send_Button" runat="server" 
                Text="Send Invitation" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup" Width="123px"/>
        &nbsp;<br />
            <asp:Label ID="Send_Success" runat="server" Text="Invitation sent!"  Visible="false"></asp:Label>

            <br />
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" 
                ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup" />
```

Question: What alternate code or work-around do you recommend for this issue?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: I don't have much exp with asp.net but did you check Page.isValid

Comment: do you have validationGroup for your button? Not much related with the issue but I also suggest using ajax ConfirmButton.

Comment: I'm guessing the population of the listbox items happens client-side?  What about the submit button action?  Is there a postback or is that client-side as well?  I'm guessing either one or both of these behaviors are what is screwing up the `RequiredFieldValidator` client-side functionality.  If the submit button does do a postback, what value do you get from `Page.IsValid` in the click handler?

Comment: Thanks for your responses @Muhammad, @Özgür, and @pseudocoder! I added extra code for the send button and carrier list box so you can get a better idea of what I'm doing. I have a validationGroup on the button, I used Page.IsValid on the click handler and it says "Nothing". Do you know how I could do this w ajax? when i select different carriers in IE8 it resets the other form values but not in IE9.

Comment: @Özgür Kaplan, thanks for your response! Can you give me some sample code for using the Ajax ConfirmButton? How do I prevent the forms from resetting?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
<strike>Add  `CausesValidation="true"` in `"lbCarriers"`</strike>

I have removed `Autopost="true"` from first listbox i.e. "lbCarriers" and it is working now.

Comment: thanks for your response. With Autopost=false on the lbCarriers, the Bundles listbox wont load any data.

Comment: Did you try CausesValidation="true" in "lbCarriers"

Comment: Yes. With CausesValidation="true" in "lbCarriers", Bundles listbox wont load any data either Do you know how to do that w Ajax?